# Solaris OS and L1 L2 L3 cache

Tags: caching, solaris

I want to get the size of L1i, L1d, L2 and L3 cache size in Solaris OS using command. The closest I get is

```
prtpicl -v| grep cache

:l3-cache-size     0x400000 
              :l3-cache-line-size        0x40
:l3-cache-associativity    0x10 
              :l1-dcache-size    0x8000 
              :l1-dcache-line-size       0x40 
              :l1-dcache-associativity   0x8
```

But I cannot get the L2 cache size, no separate L1i and L1d cache information. **How to get the cache size of all L1, L2, L3 cache?**

**OS info:**
Version:
5.11

Release :
                             Oracle Solaris 11.4 X86
  Copyright (c) 1983, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.